Преобразование текста в шестнадцатиричный формат utf-8
Программа для общения с МК дисплея. Чтобы тот мог вывести какой-то текст необходимо каждую букву преобразовать в шестнадцатиричный формат: "я кот" -> "044f 0020 043a 043e 0442", и т.п..
Соответственно ТЗ:

преобразовать любой текст заранее известного объема байтов в шестнадцатиричный формат;
так как один символ состоит из двух байтов поместить значения байтов в разные ячейки массива, служащего выходным буфером;
сократить по возможности код.

Из решений, что я находил везде используются какие-либо библиотеки, чего я делать категорически не желаю. Остановился на варианте и использованием switch структуры, теоретически самый простой, но не самый красивый вариант, т.к. со всеми используемыми символами выйдет кейсов 150. Возможно я изобретаю велосипед, есть ли более грамотное решение?
//hpp

class Interface {
void control(void);
void hex_transform(const char[], unsigned char n_symb);
unsigned char text60bytes[60]; //массив для вывода текста на 30 символов
};

//cpp

#include "Interface.hpp"
extern Interface inter;
Interface inter;

void Interface::control(void) {
inter.hex_transform("Любя, съешь щипцы, — вздохнёт.", 30);
}

void Interface::hex_transform(const char text[], unsigned char n_symb) {
char letter;
for (unsigned char n_letter = 0; n_letter < n_symb; n_letter++){
letter = text[n_letter];

switch (letter){
case /*один из символов*/:
inter.text60bytes[2*n_letter - 1] = /*byte*/;
inter.text60bytes[2*n_letter] = /*byte*/;
break; 
}
}
}


В (1) глупость написана, мне кажется. Зачем дисплею шестнадцатеричные числа? (Именно строки с шестнадцатеричными цифрами.) Раз написано "два байта на символ" (и глядя на пример), это скорее выглядит как UTF-16. Нужно выяснить, в какой кодировке у вас оригинальные строки (UTF-8) и преобразовать в желаемую кодировку (UTF-16?). Или написать u"я кот" и сразу получить строку в UTF-16.

@HolyBlackCat , конечно глупость написана, только вот во всех даташитах и мануалах одна и та же глупость, с которой приходится мне возиться. Полагаю, что изначально данные в кодировке ASCII. Можете сказать, где или как подробнее почитать про u"я кот", не видел такой формы записи, когда искал варианты решения

ASCII не может хранить русские буквы, значит кодировка какая-то другая. "где или как подробнее почитать" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal "во всех даташитах и мануалах одна и та же глупость" Ссылку бы. Слабо верится, что они такую фигню написали.

@HolyBlackCat, дисплей конечно будет воспринимать единички, нолики. С МК на МК экрана я отправлял и в десятичном виде, все там переваривалось, но отладочные программы, всякие гайды используют 16ый формат, поэтому и мне было бы его удобнее использовать. https://dwin.pro/ru/info/commands - мануал на русском, на других языках +- то же.

Если они в мануале пишут числа в шестндацтаричном виде, это ж не значит, что железке нужны строки с шестднадцатеричными цифрами, ей нужны просто байты (но вы похоже уже поняли).

Что-то я не пойму у вас проблема перевести utf-8 в utf-16? Переводите utf-8 в 4-х байтный unicode и почти всегда берете 2 младших байта (для кирилицы и латиницы это работает). Остается только с суррогатными парами разобраться. Это поскольку символы unicode на самом деле используют для кодирования 21(?) бит, а в символе utf-16 всего 16 бит, т.е. некоторые символы unicode требуют кодирование парой utf-16 символов

@avp , да я в целом то уже разобрался. Переводил из кодировки Windows 1251 в кодировку юникода. Все оказалось просто: достал по одному символу в переменную letter , взял (int) letter из чего получаю один байт данных; цифры, символы и латинские буквы такие же, как и в unicode, надо было только добавить байт 0x00, к русским буквам добавляю байт 0x04, и потом значение (int) letter - 176. В целом не знаю, на сколько это грамотное решение, но условия моего ТЗ это закрыло.
